# Challenge/response challenging on EVERY FILE?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

I have an IIS 7.5 server running a dotnet intranet app. Using Windows authentication as specified in the web.config file.

When a user first makes a call to the app, I can see the initial request is unauthenticated and receives a 401.2, as expected. The browser then request again with the username and the page is served successfully with a 200.

What happens next is unexpected, the browser then requests all the linked files anonymously and I see a challenge/response for each and every file.

Is this correct behaviour? I would have expected subsequent requests all to be authenticated.

EDIT: This works as expected using Firefox, it's IE8 quirksmode which is troublesome

This question also available on Server Fault, but noone there seems interested: https://serverfault.com/questions/581036/challenge-response-challenging-on-every-file

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the fix in gatapia's comment on his own question.

[3 requests for every resource (2 x 401.2 and 1 x 200) in a windows authenticated asp.net mvc app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973841/3-requests-for-every-resource-2-x-401-2-and-1-x-200-in-a-windows-authenticated?rq=1)